# Spring Boot Batch Processing - Adding a new column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I try to implement an example of Spring Boot Batch Processing (**CSV to h2 database**). I want to add a new column named "age" to calculate a year according to birthdate. How can I define "age" column in lineMapper? I try to use `public class UserProcessor implements ItemProcessor<UserDTO, User>`  return User DTO `(id,person_id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,country,date, age)`

Here is the sample csv file shown below.

```
id,person_id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,country,date
1,38c324d5-2d8f-4687-8862-30f15a19f26c,Melesa,Conquest,mconquest0@goodreads.com,Female,Poland,2022-09-13 09:13:05
2,082f0eff-e1ca-4f6e-8348-247b6a676547,Dodi,Jachtym,djachtym1@github.com,Polygender,Armenia,2022-03-02 09:26:13
```

I already defined date shown below in User Entity.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime date;
```

I try to calculate age with this method shown below

```
public static int calculateAge(LocalDate birthDate, LocalDate currentDate) {
        if ((birthDate != null) && (currentDate != null)) {
            return Period.between(birthDate, currentDate).getYears();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

I want to get a table shown below in h2 database.

```
id,person_id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,country,date,age
    1,38c324d5-2d8f-4687-8862-30f15a19f26c,Melesa,Conquest,mconquest0@goodreads.com,Female,Poland,2000-09-13 09:13:05,22
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot do that while reading, you will need an `ItemProcessor` to enrich the read record with the `age` or do it while writing to the database.

Comment: I second what @M.Deinum said. I added an answer with more details. HIH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LineMapper` is not the place where data should be processed. The line mapper should only be used to map a single line from the input file to an instance of the domain object.

Such calculations or data transformations are typically done in an item processor where items are amended/enriched with additional data. Please check the [Item processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/processor.html#itemProcessor) section of the reference documentation for more details about this matter.

Once items are processed, the writer can select the new column and persist it in the database.